# org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordTooLargeException: The request included a message larger than the max message size the server will accept

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka

> Im using kafka 2.11, getting the below exception
>
> 2019-03-15 16:41:19.469 ERROR 32539 --- [ad | producer-1]
>   o.s.k.support.LoggingProducerListener    : Exception thrown when
>   sending a message with key='null' and payload='[{"id":1,"name":"Tow
>   Motor","description":"Tow motor is moving from second
>   row","xcoordinate":"2264"...' to topic Kafka_Json1:
>
> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordTooLargeException: The request
>   included a message larger than the max message size the server will
>   accept.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default,Kafka accepts a message of size 1 MB. The size of your message is more than default size.

You need to change the value of the property max.request.size,message.max.bytes and  max.partition.fetch.bytes to fix this issue.

Comment: where is the damn property, could you be more specific?

Comment: @pavel_orekhov you need to find your server.properties file. mine is located at /confluent-7.0.1/etc/kafka/server.properties

Answer (score 9):

> message.max.bytes=100000000 // Increase the size in server.properties
>   file Say E.x 100 MB
>
> max.request.size=100000000 // in producer.properties file Say E.x 100 MB
>
> max.partition.fetch.bytes=100000000 // in consumer.properties file so that consumer can receive the data Say E.x 100 MB
>
> And restart the kafka broker

Answer (score 3):

Find the kafka server configuration file 'server.properties' in your system. In Ubuntu, look for the '/etc/systemd/system/kafka.service' file to get the path of 'server.properties'. Open the 'server.properties' file and add the lines below and restart kafka service to increase the message size to ~25MB.

```
max.request.size=200000000
message.max.bytes=200000000
max.partition.fetch.bytes=200000000
```

> sudo systemctl restart kafka

Non-Ubuntu users can take alternative steps in their operating system.